# Display Flex Align for responsive style?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, responsive

How to move author information to side of avatar for responsive design? Am I use flex-align or block ?
I would like change responsive design author of forum section which I attached screenshots. I tried some of code but didn't worked.

https://i.imgyukle.com/2021/03/04/NJa5KG.jpg

```css
#bbpress-forums li.bbp-body div.bbp-topic-author,
  #bbpress-forums li.bbp-body div.bbp-reply-author {
    -ms-flex-align: start;
        align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 16px;
    padding: 0 0 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-divider);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .vikinger-forum-reply-author {
    -ms-flex-align: start;
        align-items: flex-start;
```

Comment: Where is your question? Your topic is way to broad, misses details and clarity. Aswell as a question... So I get that you have some code lines and want to chaneg a design? but what do you need our help for? What kidn of help do you need? What kind of a help do you expect to get without any informations?

Comment: I changed my post and added clarity of question as you informed.

Comment: you should alsoa dd the corresponding HTML. CSS line without context are pretty much useles to us. Best would be to use a minimal reproduciable code snippet (Ctrl + m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give the style display:flex; to the author and avatars parent element.If **div.hentry ** is your parent div for avatar and author with this code they should be side by side.

```
#bbpress-forums li.bbp-body div.hentry {
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:flex-start;
align-items:center;
}
```